# Is a 8.9 MB portfolio site too large?

Tags: html, json, performance, single-page-application, image-loading

I'm extremely new and I've set up a portfolio site that consists of one html page that contains over 80 images. I've reduced the size but the images alone are 8MB. I found a page bloat update stating that the average page is over 2MB and that's too large? Do I need to store most of my images in something like a JSON array that are called up only if a user clicks on them or is 9MB okay?

Comment: Depends on whether your app is meant to only be used by top-of-the-line MacBook Pros on a fiber line (answer: not too large), or iPhone SE’s on LTE (likely too large), or five-year-old hardware on a satellite internet connection (definitely too large). See https://danluu.com/web-bloat/ for some guidance.

Comment: Well, how long do you take to download 8.9MB in your country, on smartphone with 4G/3G or wired/fios ? That answer your question.

Comment: Do you really need to load all those images at once? There are techniques to make a page appear responsive despite having so many images. Do you really need 80 images in a portfolio? Pick the ones that best portray your talent and limit the site to those. Offer the remaining images on request or on a secondary page.

Comment: Wow! That was fast, unlike my site on a satellite connection. Thank you so much Ahmed! I'm checking out your link now.

Comment: "too large" for what?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is too large if you have over 80 images for a website. This may take a lot of time for your website visitor to load the webpage. But you can create the thumbnail of each image and load the image later with some ajax request.

Use a java script to display a thumbnail and load the larger image only when the reader rolls their mouse over the thumbnail.

I use this technique when I have a lot of images I want to put on one page, but the page would be too big if I included them all at normal size at the beginning.